# how to effeciently use Pthread to generate and process combinations with multiple threads?

Tags: c, pthreads, combinations, permutation

I have 2 files, 1 containing all 16-bit numbers and another containing 144 custom 8-bit numbers.

My goal is to generate combination is like this `[16-bit][16-bit][8-bit]`, a total of 40 bits then since combinations would be like billions to trillions. I would like to distribute them to multiple threads using pThread.

Here is my code so far

Read numbers from a text file into 3 arrays:

```
    FILE *fil = fopen("pair.txt","r");
    FILE *fd = fopen("pair2.txt","r");
    size_t aln = 32768;
    size_t aln1 = 144;
    size_t numb[aln];
    size_t numb1[aln];
    size_t lump[aln1];
    int count = 0;
    char line[32768];
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fil) != NULL)
    {
        size_t num;
        if(sscanf(line, "%zu", &num) == 1)
        {
            if(count < aln)
            {
                numb[count] = num;
                numb1[count] = num;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    count = 0;
    char line1[144];
    while(fgets(line1, sizeof(line1), fd) != NULL)
    {
        size_t num;
        if(sscanf(line1, "%zu", &num) == 1)
        {
            if(count < aln1)
            {
                lump[count] = num;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Generating and distributing combinations:

```
thread ts[NUM_WORKERS];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_WORKERS; i++)
    {
        size_t x, y, end, d;
        //get value from arrays
        for(size_t a = 0; a < sizeof(numb); a++)
        {
            x = numb[a];
            for(size_t b = 0; b < sizeof(numb1); b++)
            {
                y = numb1[b];
                for(size_t c = 0; c < sizeof(numb2); c++)
                {
                    end = numb2[c];
                    for(size_t f = 0; f < sizeof(lump); f++)
                    {
                        d = lump[f];
                        ts[i] = spawn_worker(x, y, end, d);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_WORKERS; i++)
        join_thread(ts[i]);
```

Here is the Spawn_worker function:

```
static thread spawn_worker(size_t x, size_t y, size_t end, size_t d)
{
    struct info *info = (struct info *)malloc(sizeof(struct info));
    assert(info != NULL);
    //info->n = n;
    info->x = x;
    info->y = y;
    info->end = end;
    info->d = d;
    thread t = spawn_thread(worker, info);
    if (t == (thread)NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: failed to spawn thread");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return t;
}
```

And the worker function:

```
static void *worker(void *arg)
{
    struct info *info = (struct info *)arg;
    size_t n = info->n;
    size_t x = info->x;
    size_t y = info->y;
    size_t end = info->end;
    size_t d = info->d;
    free(info);
    uint160_t target;
    memcpy(&target, &targ, sizeof(target));
   // COMPUTE WORK:
    if (stop)
        return NULL;
    uint160_t ad = f(x, y, end, d);
    if (is_equal(n, ad, target))
    {
        size_t w = 80;
        printf("\n");
        uint256_t key0 = gen_priv_key(x, y, end, d);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(key0); i++)
            {
               printf("%.2X", key0.i8[i]);
            }
           printf("\n");
        if (!is_equal(w, ad, target))
        {
            stop = true;
            uint256_t key1 = gen_priv_key(x, y, end, d);
            //print private key here
            printf("=====================================================\n");
            for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(key1); i++)
            {
               printf("%.2X", key1.i8[i]);
           }
           printf("=======================================================\n");
        }
    }
```

But i do not think i am doing it right, I am not a C master but i think generating all combinations and store them, then distribute them to threads is the best approach.
I have 32 core, 64 threads on a **256GB RAM** + **8TB** storage.

Please how can i efficiently distribute this work?

Please note each combination is 40 bits, meaning 2 `16-bit` numbers and 1 `8-bit` number.

example combination: `[34628,37562,4096]`, so not to be confused with 4096 in place of 8-bit numbers, its a representation 1000, as in ten with zeros appended thus why the last array has only 144 values (10 to 9f).

i hope this clarifies a little more.

Comment: To begin with I would use a `struct` to put all the different values together, and then a single array of this structure. That will also make it easier to pass one single array to the threads, rather than needing multiple global variables.

Comment: And your loops using `sizeof` are *not* correct. `sizeof` results in the size in *bytes*, not elements, so all those loops will go way out of bounds of the arrays.

Comment: Unh... Better buy more storage... Looks like you're only using 0-32767 (15 bits) for those 16 bit values... The left most pair would require (roughly) 32768x144 x 8 bytes (64 bit)... call it 38Mb... Prepend another 15 bits (32768 values) and we're up to 1237Gb... Finally, the most significant 15 bits... 40,532Tb of storage required... Ambitious much? (Probably off topic, since you were asking about threads...)

Comment: Room's gone quiet... Simpler: 2^(3*15) * 144 * 8 ~ 40.5 Petabytes...

Comment: Your whole approach to this problem appears to be hopelessly inefficient. If your using all 15 bit numbers, you don't need them in a file or array, you can just generate them on the fly by counting. If you want to call your function spawn_worker() for each combination, then you have over 5 quadrillion calls, which even if your function is something simple is not going to complete in reasonable time. You probably need to look into GPGPU computing (CUDA, OpenCL, etc.) to get this done in reasonable time.

Comment: If you insist on trying to do it with pthreads, then I recommend doing it in batches of a million or so combinations at a time. Then you need a buffer for each million combinations each thread you're using, fill the buffers and call the threads repeatedly until it's done. You don't want to create a thread and join it again for every individual combination. There's an overhead of ~100k machine cycles to creating a thread so even the simplest of functions would take 3000 years or so to do it that way.

Comment: You haven't posted the `spawn_worker` function but if I understand this correct, you want to start a new thread for every combination! That woul be 32768 * 32768 * 32768 * 144 = 5066549580791808 threads. That's a very bad idea.

Comment: yeah i figured, so reducing combinations would be better. Lets say 32768*32768*144 shared in some way by 64 threads. but i still have no idea how to correctly multithread it though.

Comment: This code is my big breakthrough and a major success of Large BTC Collider so basically 56 bits would find about 37 solutions before hitting the target but reducing it 40 bits would give me few hundreds but its fine if doable in days so i can prove my theory

Comment: There are a lot of unclear things going on here but.... Well, in general a thread needs a "sufficiently large job" before it's even worth to start a thread. If you want 64 threads you could split the outer array in 64 equal sized sub-arrays. 32768 / 64 is 512. So the first thread handles index 0 to 511. The second thread handles index 512 to 1023. And so on.... That said, it all depends on what the threads will do with the generated values. It's not really clear from your description. Are the values to be stored in **one** file? How about order? ....

Comment: .... Also notice that the threads may generate data much faster than your file system can handle so the limit can be the file system. Not the number of threads.

Comment: The approach you should take depends on how heavy is your spawn_worker() function. I suggest you give us some indication by no of cycles, ms, us, or ns on what hardware each call takes. You don't want to spend a month writing a program that will take a hundred years to run.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to generate a massive array (5x10^15 elements) whose elements contain "gaps" (like holes in Swiss cheese) then perform some operation(s) to "_find about 37 solutions before hitting the target_"... If those operations involve _ricocheting_ from one element to another, it's likely you need only generate (on the fly) the values required. There may be no need to generate the other 99.999999... per cent of the array... Give that some thought...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all comments i now managed to generate combinations on the fly in batches of 2 billion per thread.
Here is how i modified the code:

```
FILE *fd = fopen("pair2.txt","r");
    size_t aln = 32768;
    size_t aln1 = 144;  
    int count = 0;
    char line1[144];
    while(fgets(line1, 144, fd) != NULL)
    {
        size_t num;
        if(sscanf(line1, "%zu", &num) == 1)
        {
            if(count < aln1)
            {
                lump[count] = num;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    size_t bat[65] = {
    32768, 33280, 33792, 34304, 34816, 35328, 35840, 36352, 36864, 37376, 
    37888, 38400, 38912, 39424, 39936, 40448, 40960, 41472, 41984, 42496, 
    43008, 43520, 44032, 44544, 45056, 45568, 46080, 46592, 47104, 47616, 
    48128, 48640, 49152, 49664, 50176, 50688, 51200, 51712, 52224, 52736, 
    53248, 53760, 54272, 54784, 55296, 55808, 56320, 56832, 57344, 57856, 
    58368, 58880, 59392, 59904, 60416, 60928, 61440, 61952, 62464, 62976, 
    63488, 64000, 64512, 65024, 65536};
 if (!stop)
    {
        thread ts[NUM_WORKERS];
        // Start new work:
        for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_WORKERS; i++)
        {
            ts[i] = spawn_worker(bat[i], bat[i+1],n);           
        }
        for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_WORKERS; i++)
            join_thread(ts[i]);
            
     }
    printf("|\n");
```

Then the `Spawn_worker` and `worker` functions:

```
static thread spawn_worker(size_t x, size_t y, size_t n)
{
    struct info *info = (struct info *)malloc(sizeof(struct info));
    assert(info != NULL);
    info->x = x;
    info->y = y;
    info->n = n;
    thread t = spawn_thread(worker, info);
    if (t == (thread)NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: failed to spawn thread");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return t;
}

static void *worker(void *arg)
{
    struct info *info = (struct info *)arg;
    size_t x = info->x;
    size_t y = info->y;
    size_t n = info->n;
    free(info);
    uint160_t target;
    memcpy(&target, &targ, sizeof(target));
   // COMPUTE WORK:
    for(size_t a = x; a <= y; a++)
    {
        if (stop)
            return NULL;
        for(size_t b = 32769; b <= 65536; b++)
        {
            if (stop)
                return NULL;
            for(size_t c = 0; c <= 144; c++)
            {
                if (stop)
                    return NULL;
                size_t lp = lump[c];
                uint160_t ad = f(a, b, lp);
                if (is_equal(n, ad, target))
                {
                    size_t w = 80;
                    printf("\n");
                    uint256_t key0 = gen_priv_key(a, b, lp);
                    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(key0); i++)
                        {
                           printf("%.2X", key0.i8[i]);
                        }
                       printf("\n");
                    if (is_equal(w, ad, target))
                    {
                        stop = true;
                        uint256_t key1 = gen_priv_key(a, b, lp);
                        //print private key here
                        printf("=====================================================\n");
                        for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(key1); i++)
                        {
                           printf("%.2X", key1.i8[i]);
                         }
                       printf("=======================================================\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    }
```

Then i checked if 64 worker threads are running and yes they are.
note: **stop** flag is used to stop if solution is found by any thread.